# Rayleigh quotient of matrix $A$ is diagonal entry of $Q^*AQ$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$ be a matrix. Show that if $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a Rayleigh quotient of $A$ then $z$ is a diagonal entry of $Q^*AQ$, with $Q$ a unitary $m\times m$ matrix.

My approach:

We have that given a non-zero vector $x$, $z=\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$. Let $x:=Qy$ for some unitary $Q$. Then

$$z=\frac{(Qy)^*AQy}{\|y\|\|y\|}$$
This shows that $z$ is a Rayleigh quotient for $Q^*AQ$.
WLOG, let $(Q^*AQ)_{ii}$ be the $ii$th diagonal entry of $Q^*AQ$. Then $(Q^*AQ)_{ii}= q_i^*Aq_i$. Set $q_i=\frac{Qy}{\|y\|}$. Construct $Q$ by a Gram-Schmidt process. This proves that there exists unitary $Q$ such that $z$ is a diagonal entry of $Q^*AQ$ for $x$.

Do you think my proof is consistent?
Would appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea, but a few aspects of your proof are problematic:

> We have that given a non-zero vector $x$, $z=\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$.

Your phrasing is a bit off here.  You're implying that for any choice of non-zero vector $x$, we have $z=\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$, which is not what you mean.  I would say

*By the definition of a Rayleigh quotient, there exists a non-zero vector $x$ such that $z = \frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}$*

On to the next part:

> Let $x:=Qy$ for some unitary $Q$. Then
>   $$z=\frac{(Qy)^*AQy}{\|y\|\|y\|}$$
>   This shows that $z$ is a Rayleigh quotient for $Q^*AQ$.

I agree with your conclusion that $z$ is a Rayleigh quotient of $Q^*AQ$.  The rest is confusing.  Writing $x:=Qy$ makes no sense in this context: $x$ was defined earlier, so we're not defining it now.  Also, you never said what $y$ is.

> WLOG, let $(Q^*AQ)_{ii}$ be the $ii$th diagonal entry of $Q^*AQ$.

WLOG means "without loss of generality".  I have no idea how that is supposed to apply here.

> Then $(Q^*AQ)_{ii}= q_i^*Aq_i$. Set $q_i=\frac{Qy}{\|y\|}$. Construct $Q$ by a Gram-Schmidt process.

This is confusing.  To begin, you're defining $q_i$ to be the $i$th column of $Q$.  Then, you're saying (or trying to say) that we should construct a $Q$ that has $q_i$ as its $i$th column.  Why are we constructing $Q$ if we already have $Q$?

> This proves that there exists unitary $Q$ such that $z$ is a diagonal entry of $Q^*AQ$ for $x$.

The "for $x$" at the end here makes no sense; perhaps it's there by mistake.

---

Here's a more concise proof, which is readable to me:

> Because $z$ is a Rayleigh quotient of $A$, there exists a unit vector $x$ such that $z = \frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x} = x^*Ax$. Let $Q$ denote a unitary matrix that has $x$ as its first column (such a matrix could be constructed by a Gram-Schmidt process).  We note that
>   $$
> (Q^*AQ)_{11} = q_1^*Aq_1 = x^*Ax = z
> $$
>   Thus, we see that $z$ is a diagonal entry of the matrix $Q^*AQ$.

Comment: Thanks, I was laughing like crazy while reading your remarks about what I wrote in my version. But, AFAIK, there can be more than one Rayleigh quotient, so that $x$ is not unique.

Comment: Indeed, $x$ is not unique (for instance, $-x$ will produce the same quotient).  Note that the phrasing "there exists a (unit) vector $x$ such that $z = \frac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}$" does not imply that the $x$ in question is unique.

Comment: Also, you're welcome. While I'm glad you got a laugh out of it, I hope that it's clear that my comments were not meant to be insulting.

Comment: It's a Rayleigh quotient defined for any matrix $A$ and any non-zero $x$? That's what I'm getting from more than one definitions I've found. I didn't find anything insulting in your comments, quite the contrary. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Yes: a Rayleigh quotient is defined for any matrix $A$ and any non-zero $x$.  I am choosing a unit vector; note in general that $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ produces the same Rayleigh quotient as $x$ (for the same $A$).